# Will C++ compiler generate code for each template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two questions about templates in C++. Let's imagine I have written a simple List  and now I want to use it in my program to store pointers to different object types (A*, B* ... ALot*). My colleague says that for each type there will be generated a dedicated piece of code, even though all pointers in fact have the same size.

If this is true, can somebody explain me why? For example in Java generics have the same purpose as templates for pointers in C++. Generics are only used for pre-compile type checking and are stripped down before compilation. And of course the same byte code is used for everything.

Second question is, will dedicated code be also generated for char and short (considering that they both have the same size and there are no specialization).

If this makes any difference, we are talking about embedded applications.

I have found a similar question, but it did not completely answer my question: [Do C++ template classes duplicate code for each pointer type used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914030/do-c-template-classes-duplicate-code-for-each-pointer-type-used)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how did it not completely answer your question? What did it not answer?

Comment: `char` and `short` **do not** have the same size, `char` is 1 byte, `short` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Java Generics have pretty much nothing in common with C++ templates. Except the `<>` syntax maybe.

Comment: Also, don't generalize generics. There are multiple types of generics. Java uses the very horrible type-erasure method for generics. .NET languages (C#, VB etc) use reificated generics. Reificated generics are not "stripped down" before compilation.

Comment: @Mat I know, and I wanted to edit the comment to say "usually" after I noticed, but that's no longer possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do C++ template classes duplicate code for each pointer type used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914030/do-c-template-classes-duplicate-code-for-each-pointer-type-used)

Comment: I was talking exactly about Java generics. As horrible as they may be, they are fulfilling their purpose very good - providing Object type checking before compilation. As for short and char, they are both 8 bits on AVRs:-)

Comment: Yes, I have found the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914030/do-c-template-classes-duplicate-code-for-each-pointer-type-used , but it does not answer the question "why?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have two questions about templates in C++. Let's imagine I have written a simple List and now I want to use it in my program to store pointers to different object types (A*, B* ... ALot*). My colleague says that for each type there will be generated a dedicated piece of code, even though all pointers in fact have the same size.

Yes, this is equivalent to having both functions written.

Some linkers will detect the identical functions, and eliminate them.  Some libraries are aware that their linker doesn't have this feature, and factor out common code into a single implementation, leaving only a casting wrapper around the common code.  Ie, a `std::vector<T*>` specialization may forward all work to a `std::vector<void*>` then do casting on the way out.

Now, comdat folding is delicate: it is relatively easy to make functions you think are identical, but end up not being the same, so two functions are generated.  As a toy example, you could go off and print the typename via `typeid(x).name()`.  Now each version of the function is distinct, and they cannot be eliminated.

In some cases, you might do something like this thinking that it is a run time property that differs, and hence identical code will be created, and the identical functions eliminated -- but a smart C++ compiler might figure out what you did, use the as-if rule and turn it into a compile-time check, and block not-really-identical functions from being treated as identical.

> If this is true, can somebody explain me why? For example in Java generics have the same purpose as templates for pointers in C++. Generics are only used for per-compile type checking and are stripped down before compilation. And of course the same byte code is used for everything.

No, they aren't.  Generics are roughly equivalent to the C++ technique of type erasure, such as what `std::function<void()>` does to store any callable object.  In C++, type erasure is often done via templates, but not all uses of templates are type erasure!

The things that C++ does with templates that are not in essence type erasure are generally impossible to do with Java generics.

In C++, you *can* create a type erased container of pointers using templates, but `std::vector` doesn't do that -- it creates an actual container of pointers.  The advantage to this is that all type checking on the `std::vector` is done at compile time, so there doesn't have to be any run time checks: a safe type-erased `std::vector` may require run time type checking and the associated overhead involved.

> Second question is, will dedicated code be also generated for char and short (considering that they both have the same size and there are no specialization).

They are distinct types.  I can write code that will behave differently with a `char` or `short` value.  As an example:

```
std::cout << x << "\n";
```

with x being a `short`, this print an integer whose value is `x` -- with `x` being a `char`, this prints the character corresponding to `x`.

Now, almost all template code exists in header files, and is implicitly `inline`.  While `inline` doesn't mean what most folk think it means, it does mean that the compiler can hoist the code into the calling context easily.

> If this makes any difference, we are talking about embedded applications.

What really makes a difference is what your particular compiler and linker is, and what settings and flags they have active.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is maybe.  In general, each instantiation of a
template is a unique type, with a unique implementation, and
will result in a totally independent instance of the code.
Merging the instances is possible, but would be considered
"optimization" (under the "as if" rule), and this optimization
isn't wide spread.

With regards to comparisons with Java, there are several points
to keep in mind:

- C++ uses value semantics by default.  An `std::vector`, for
  example, will actually insert copies.  And whether you're
  copying a `short` or a `double` does make a difference in the
  generated code.  In Java, `short` and `double` will be boxed,
  and the generated code will clone a boxed instance in some way;
  cloning doesn't require different code, since it calls a virtual
  function of `Object`, but physically copying does.
- C++ is far more powerful than Java.  In particular, it allows
  comparing things like the address of functions, and it requires
  that the functions in different instantiations of templates have
  different addresses.  Usually, this is not an important point,
  and I can easily imagine a compiler with an option which tells
  it to ignore this point, and to merge instances which are
  identical at the binary level.  (I think VC++ has something like
  this.)

Another issue is that the implementation of a template in C++
must be present in the header file.  In Java, of course,
everything must be present, always, so this issue affects all
classes, not just template.  This is, of course, one of the
reasons why Java is not appropriate for large applications.  But
it means that you don't want any complicated functionality in a
template; doing so loses one of the major advantages of C++,
compared to Java (and many other languages).  In fact, it's not
rare, when implementing complicated functionality in templates,
to have the template inherit from a non-template class which
does most of the implementation in terms of `void*`.  While
implementing large blocks of code in terms of `void*` is never
fun, it does have the advantage of offering the best of both
worlds to the client: the implementation is hidden in compiled
files, invisible in any way, shape or manner to the client.

Comment: Hi James, thanks a lot for your answer! I can argue about Java being not suitable for large applications :-) but I won't. My question was only about a template list and other containers, which contain absolutely no logic which can manipulate these objects except for storing them. If you say that exactly same binary code may be merged, I am happy.

Comment: @YuriyKulikov I say that it may be merged under the "as if" rule, not that it will be merged.  For things like `std::list`, the code is all inline and trivial; after inlining, there will probably be nothing left to merge.  (This is, of course, what the JIT compiler does in Java.  Formally, the instantiation of a Java template is full of type conversions, which correspond to a `dynamic_cast` in C++, and are fairly expensive in runtime.  In practice, the JIT will be able to eliminate most, if not all of the checked conversions, and do the equivalent of a `static_cast`.)