# Boost.Pointer Container made obsolete by std::unique_ptr in C++11/14?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl, smart-pointers

Does `std::unique_ptr` make **Boost.Pointer Container** library obsolete in C++11/14?

In C++98/03 there isn't move semantics, and a smart pointer like `shared_ptr` has reference-counting related *overhead* (both for the ref counting block, and the *interlocked* increment/decrements) if compared to raw pointers. So something like `std::vector<shared_ptr<T>>` has overhead if compared to `std::vector<T*>`.

But is `std::vector<std::unqiue_ptr<T>>` just as **efficient** as `std::vector<T*>` (no reference counting  overhead), *and* in addition **safe** in regard to exceptions and automatic destruction (i.e. `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` destructor will *automatically* call the destructors for the `T` items whose pointers are stored in the `vector`)?

If so, does Boost.Pointer Container still have a valid useful place in C++11/14 code, or is it just obsolete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As James mentions in his answer, the Boost.Pointer containers offer a more intuitive interface as compared to what you get by sticking a `unique_ptr` into a standard library container.

Aside from that, `boost::ptr_vector<T>` (and friends) store the pointed to type as a `void *` underneath, so you don't get an entire class template instantiation for every `T`. This is not the case with `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: the `void*` hoisting was also a "known optimization" to reduce template instantiations for `std::vector<T*>`, but neither the current libc++ nor the current libstdc++ use that optimization anymore. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13914629/819272) by @JonathanWakely.

Answer (score 11):

It's not obslete; it has a completely different and more
intuitive interface than `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: Long ago, but... can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `std::vector<std::unqiue_ptr<T>>`

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
};


vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> bar;
bar.push_back(make_unique<Foo>(1));
cout << bar[0]->a << endl; // rvalue, is ok
Foo *foo = bar[1].get(); // try to use a pointer, this interface "bar[1].get()" is awful
```

Boost.Pointer Container certainly has more intuitive interface.